# Count companies per country based on certain criteria (in Excel)

Tags: excel

I have the following 2 excel sheets in the same workbook:

companies:

```
    A          B            C         D
1 COMPANY   COUNTRY      SECTOR    SUBSECTOR
2 Apple     USA          Hardware  Consumer
3 Microsoft USA          Software  Consumer and Business
4 Samsung   Taiwan       Hardware  Business
5 Philips   Netherlands  Hardware  Consumer and Business
6 Tulip     Netherlands  Hardware  Business
```

countries:

```
    A             B         C           D
1 COUNTRY      NUM_COMP  NUM_SECTOR  NUM_SUB
2 USA             2         1           0
3 Taiwan          1         1           0
4 Netherlands     2         2           1
```

In sheet `countries` column `B` I need the number of companies per country. Thanks to @barry houdini I use the following:

```
=COUNTIF(companies!B$2:B$4;A2)
```

However, I need to additional counts. In column `C`: a count of companies per country in the `Hardware` sector. In column `D`: a count of companies per country that are in the `Hardware` sector *and* in the `Consumer and Business` subsector. I have made these counts manually above, but need a formula to count them automagically.

Can anyone help me on my way? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For countries in hardware sector try COUNTIFS like this

`=COUNTIFS(companies!B$2:B$100;A2;companies!C$2:C$100;"hardware")`

You can add more conditions so for your second count try

`=COUNTIFS(companies!B$2:B$100;A2;companies!C$2:C$100;"hardware";companies!D$2:D$100;"Consumer and Business")`

You need Excel 2007 or later to use `COUNTIFS`